# Where should I put these strange files in the file structure for Flask app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

So I downloaded a template for a website, with the aim to use it in my Flask app. I know the basic file structure of Flask app is this:

```
-app
 app.py
 -static
  -images
    -image files
  -style
    -css files
 -templates
  -html files
```

But when I opened the folder of the template code, I found all these strange files and I couldn't decide where to put them.

The original files:

[image]

So I put the css, fonts, images, js folders into the static folder and left the rest of the files in the templates folder along with index.html (ignore `index - Copy.html`, that is a copy I made of the original `index.html` file), updated the paths of css and js files inside the HTML document and executed app.py.

The file ran but most of the text of index.html was not loading and only one image was being displayed. I checked the logs in the command line terminal and discovered that most of the css was not even getting called.

What am I doing wrong? How should I arrange these files?

Comment: You'll have to also look at your browser's inspector's network tab to see what requests are getting made and which ones might be 404-ing.

Comment: Also, make sure you've actually updated the paths within the new `index.html` to relfect their new location on disk.  Find every `link` and `script` tag in the html file and replace the URLS with something like `{{ url_for('static', filename='css/example.css') }}` for every one.  Then check the network tab again as @AKX says :-)

Comment: I have checked the entire html file and updated all such parts. Also, I checked the network tab in the browser and the result is same- the rest of the images aren't even being called and the few css and image which is called has 200 status.

Comment: https://colorlib.com/preview/#digilab

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you should connect styles in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}">
```